# Apache-Commons-DBCP Issue

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-dbcp

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:810) 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver.connect(PoolingDriver.java:180) 
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582) 
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
```

The application becomes unresponsive in production server.

verified that the connection are closed properly in  finally block. 
What are the probable scenarios for this situation

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little information you've provided above, I'd say that you've exceeded the maximum capacity of the pool. The stack-trace that you've pasted, shows a `wait()` after a `borrowObject`. To me this means that you have a bunch of open/active connections and `borrowObject` is waiting for a connection to be returned to the pool.

Comment: Yes i thought the same and have verified that the connection is being returned back to the pool in finally block.

Comment: Try the following:
1. start the application
2. make a DB request
3. do a thread dump
4. make a bunch of DB requests
5. do a thread dump

Do you have a multiple stack-traces similar to the original one you posted?